# How to represent PostgreSQL interval in Go

Tags: postgresql, go

How to represent PostgreSQL interval in Go?

My struct looks like this:

```
type Product struct {
    Id              int
    Name            string
    Type            int
    Price           float64
    Execution_time  ????
}
```

The execution_time field on my database is `interval`.

Comment: You might be on your own there sir. Not my area of expertise but I read the `interval` type is a 16 byte so I don't know how it would map to any type in Go without conversion. Might be worth checking out this package; https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/ or just writing a method to convert the 16 byte binary value to a `time.Time`... Alternately, I would recommend against using that type in Postgres unless it's completely necessary. It rarely should be since standard sized types cover most of the daterange we care about.

Comment: You will probably want to make sure that the database is using the iso_8601 format (which looks like `P3DT4H5M6S`), receive it as a string and then use something like https://github.com/ChannelMeter/iso8601duration to parse it. You may then convert it to a `time.Duration` if you wish.

Comment: Note that a `time.Duration` stores durations up to ~±290 years (with nanosecond precision) whereas a PostgreSQL interval stores up to ~±178000000 years (with microsecond precision).

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/apaxa-go/pgtypes/blob/master/interval.go). `precision` field may be omitted - it does not required by PostgreSQL interval type itself (it is just an implementation details).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're OK with conforming to the `time.Duration` limits and you need only seconds accuracy you could:

- Create the table with a SECOND precision

  `...
  someInterval INTERVAL SECOND(0),
  ...`
- Convert INTERVAL into seconds:

  `SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM someInterval) FROM someTable;`
- Use [time.Duration::Seconds](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Seconds) to insert data to prepared statements

Comment: for reading again you would have to implement scan & value.

Answer (score 7):

The best answer I've [come across](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4954) is to use `bigint` in your schema, and implement `Value` & `Scan` on a wrapper type for `time.Duration`.

```
// Duration lets us convert between a bigint in Postgres and time.Duration
// in Go
type Duration time.Duration

// Value converts Duration to a primitive value ready to written to a database.
func (d Duration) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return driver.Value(int64(d)), nil
}

// Scan reads a Duration value from database driver type.
func (d *Duration) Scan(raw interface{}) error {
    switch v := raw.(type) {
    case int64:
        *d = Duration(v)
    case nil:
        *d = Duration(0)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot sql.Scan() strfmt.Duration from: %#v", v)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Unfortunately, you'll sacrifice the ability to do interval arithmetic inside queries - unless some clever fellow wants to post the type conversion for `bigint` => `interval`.

Comment: note that if you are using this query `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM <datetime2 - datetime>) AS duration_in_seconds` you get seconds. `Duration(v)` by default accepts nanoseconds. So you'd have to do `Duration(time.Duration(v) * time.Second)` to get the right value.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to wrap the `time.Duration` type in a wrapper type, and on it provide implementations of `sql.Scanner` and `driver.Valuer`.

```golang
// PgDuration wraps a time.Duration to provide implementations of
// sql.Scanner and driver.Valuer for reading/writing from/to a DB.
type PgDuration time.Duration
```

Postgres appears to be quite flexible with the format provided when inserting into an `INTERVAL` column. The default format returned by calling `String()` on a duration is accepted, so for the implementation of `driver.Value`, simply call it:

```golang
// Value converts the PgDuration into a string.
func (d PgDuration) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return time.Duration(d).String(), nil
}
```

When retrieving an `INTERVAL` value from Postgres, it returns it in a format that is not so easily parsed by Go (ex. `"2 days 05:00:30.000250"`), so we need to do some manual parsing in our implementation of `sql.Scanner`. In my case, I only care about supporting hours, minutes, and seconds, so I implemented it as follows:

```golang
// Scan converts the received string in the format hh:mm:ss into a PgDuration.
func (d *PgDuration) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case string:
        // Convert format of hh:mm:ss into format parseable by time.ParseDuration()
        v = strings.Replace(v, ":", "h", 1)
        v = strings.Replace(v, ":", "m", 1)
        v += "s"
        dur, err := time.ParseDuration(v)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        *d = PgDuration(dur)
        return nil
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot sql.Scan() PgDuration from: %#v", v)
    }
}
```

If you need to support other duration units, you can start with a similar approach, and handle the additional units appropriately.

Also, if you happen to be using the GORM library to automatically migrate your table, you will also want to provide an implementation of GORM's `migrator.GormDataTypeInterface`:

```golang
// GormDataType tells GORM to use the INTERVAL data type for a PgDuration column.
func (PgDuration) GormDataType() string {
    return "INTERVAL"
}
```